# Botón back con location.hash y AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas estoy haciendo una aplicación que es un comandero. Es para un restaurante de pizzas y alguna cosa más. Lo estoy haciendo en un servidor y lo abro en la máquina TPV de este local.

Me encuentro con dificultades a la hora de ir navegando por los productos, es decir primero cargo todas las categorías, si pulso por ejemplo en Pizzas, a través de AJAX saco el los productos que hay en Pizzas, una vez elija una pizza a través de AJAX me cargara de nuevo datos para elegir tamaño y algunas opciones más, pero si quiero i volviendo paso a paso para detrás no se como hacerlo.

Buscando y buscando y bajo mi conocimiento he encontrado `window.location.hash` donde en cada `success` del ajax le asigno un elemento a la URL por ejemplo `#categorias`.

Con el código que muestro abajo, el botón que retrocede si me cambia la url pero no el contenido de la pantalla. Solo e mostrado dos pasos la iteración de las categorías y la elección del producto.

**HTML**

```
@foreach ($categorias as $item)
    <div class="lasCat center" data-id="{{ $item->id }}">
        <img src="{{URL::asset($item->foto)}}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
         <h2>{{ $item->name }}</h2>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.location.hash = "#categorias";
    
    $('.lasCat').on('click',function prueba() {
        var idCategoria = $(this).data("id");
        var url = '/saca-productos';
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: {'idCategoria': idCategoria},

            success: function (resultado){
                $('#zonaProductos').empty();

                window.location.hash = "#"+ resultado.categoria.slug +"";

                $('#muestra__boton').html("<a id=\"backLink\" class=\"volver__btn\"><i class=\"fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left\"></i> Volver</a>");

                $("#backLink").click(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    window.history.back(1);
                });

                $.each(resultado , function(index, productos) { 
                    //console.log(index, productos)
                    for(i = 0; i < productos.length; i++){
                        $('#zonaProductos').append('<div class="lasCat seleccionProducto center" data-id="'+ productos[i].id +'">\
                                                        <img src="'+ productos[i].foto +'" alt="" class="img-fluid">\
                                                        <h2>'+ productos[i].name +'</h2>\
                                                    </div>');
                                                    
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(e) { $("#zonaProductos").html("Sucedió un error!") }
        });
    });
```

Alguna sugerencia....

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para agregar código HTML de, al menos, una categoría, para saber cómo tomar los datos de ahí para la petición AJAX.

Comment: Ya te lo he puesto @Triby es una iteración desde la base de datos

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices de `if(hash == '#uno') {` pero al ser una iteración como se al que pulso? Por eso dices que los estoy generando manualmente no?

Comment: ¿Categorías y productos tienen _slug_ para usar en _hash_?

Comment: Si lo tienen Triby , lo que pasa que en la tabla de producto guardo el `id` de la categoría en lugar del slug

Comment: He modificado lo de consultar por la id, ahora lo consulto todo por el `slug` @Triby

Comment: No es necesario, puedes seguir haciendo la consulta por ID, revisa la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Ahora sigo probando tengo que salir 20min, parece que funciona pero he de hacer unos ajustes, supongo que don pones `// Muestras solo las categorías` tengo que iterar con JavaScript las categorias??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para trabajar con historial, no debes depender de clic en los enlaces, sino de cambios en la barra de direcciones, específicamente, del evento [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) y cargar el nuevo contenido de acuerdo al *hash* actual.

Insisto: **trabaja solo con el historial, no con clics**

Crea una función para analizar el *hash*, si está vacío, **debes mostrar la página inicial (categorías)**, de lo contrario, ejecutar la petición AJAX que corresponda a cada uno. Esta función debe estar asignada al evento `hashchange` y, además, ejecutarse al cargar la página, por si ingresan directamente o pulsan F5 para recargar.

En el HTML, crea enlaces para activar cada categoría, de forma que puedas obtener fácilmente la información necesaria desde el *hash* (*slug* de categoría):

```
@foreach ($categorias as $item)
    <div class="lasCat center">
        <a href="#{{ $item->slug }}" data-id="{{ $item->id }}">
            <img src="{{URL::asset($item->foto)}}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            <h2>{{ $item->name }}</h2>
        </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Es posible que esto afecte los estilos, pero sería algo sencillo de resolver.

Luego, en Javascript vas a tomar esos datos desde el evento:

```js
// Analizar hash en una función
function hashChanged() {
    let hash = window.location.hash;
    console.log(hash);
    if(hash == '') {
        // Muestras solo las categorías
        // Ocultas productos y todo lo que no deba aparecer
    } else {
        // Obtener Enlace
        let link = $(`a[href="${hash}"]`);
        // Ejecutar función AJAX para cargar productos de categorías
        cargaProductos($(link).data('id'));
    }
}

// Ejecutar función cuando el hash se modifique
$(window).on('hashchange', hashChanged);

// Ejecutar al cargar la página, por si se ingresa directo (o se recarga)
$(function() {
    hashChanged();
});
// Asignar evento al botón
$('#back').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.back();
});

// Cambiar el hash manualmente no es recomendable
$('#manual').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = '#manual';
});

// Recibe ID de categoría como parámetro
function cargaProductos(idCategoria) {
    console.log(idCategoria);
    // No es necesario asignar evento click,
    // porque se trabaja con historial
            let url = '/saca-productos';
            $.ajax({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                data: {'idCategoria': idCategoria},
    
                success: function (resultado){
                    // No modifiques el hash el enlace lo actualizó
                    // window.location.hash = "#"+ resultado.categoria.slug +"";

                    $('#zonaProductos').empty();
                    $.each(resultado , function(index, productos) { 
                        //console.log(index, productos)
                        for(i = 0; i < productos.length; i++){
                            $('#zonaProductos').append('<div class="lasCat seleccionProducto center" data-id="'+ productos[i].id +'">\
                                                            <img src="'+ productos[i].foto +'" alt="" class="img-fluid">\
                                                            <h2>'+ productos[i].name +'</h2>\
                                                        </div>');
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function(e) { $("#zonaProductos").html("Sucedió un error!") }
            });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#uno" data-id="1">Uno</a></li>
    <li><a href="#dos" data-id="2">Dos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tres" data-id="3">Tres</a></li>
</ul>
<button id="back">Volver</button>
<button id="manual">Manual</button>
```

Como comentario final, prueba el fragmento de código y funciona correctamente con los enlaces y el botón "Volver", pero el comportamiento puede ser errático con el botón "Manual". Si necesitas asignar un hash, no debes hacerlo directo, sino con [history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

Ahora, si vas a manejar *hash* con los productos, tienes que buscar una forma de diferenciarlos de las categorías, pero depende de la estructura de los *slugs* de cada uno.

Comment: Hola @Triby te comento. Viendo la pregunta entiendes que la página ni se tiene que recargar en ningún momento no?

Comment: @Miguel, sí, eso lo tengo claro, pero debes tener en consideración las acciones involuntarias (¿o no?) de los usuarios. En una computadora basta con pulsar F5 y en un móvil con deslizar abajo para recargar y, si no lo tienes contemplado, no sabes qué es lo que se va a mostrar.

Comment: ok ok! voy a probar como me dices, llevo toda la tarde con esto, haber como monto esto con el AJAX, gracias @Triby

Comment: Hola @Triby de nuevo, revisa por favor la actualización del final de mi pregunta, al final consigo lo mismo que antes, solo sale el `#item` como antes pero no cambia el ajax, seguro que lo estoy haciendo mal, por favor revisa

Comment: @Miguel, no hay cambio real en ese código, sigues modificando el hash manualmente. ¿Cómo llegas a `#categorías`?

Comment: Al final esa última ventana la abro con un modal, marco la respuesta como buena ya que me funciono a la perfección lo que me pusiste, gracias @Triby . Voy a borrar tambien los comentarios sobrantes